# Как через span выбрать div?

Tags: css

В коде

```
<div></div><span></span>
```

выбрать span при некоторых ситуациях можно написав

```
div + span
```

а как написать наоборот, т.е. через span выбрать div?
Т.е. по логике как будто бы так

```
span - div
```

Comment: Выборка предыдущего элемента с помощью CSS уже обсуждалась тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433489/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-css-%D0%BF%D0%BE-hover/433493#433493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только скриптом: `$('span').prev()`. Либо пересматривать код `html`.