# Анимация в CSS по hover

Tags: css

Необходимо анимировать элемент в CSS. Необходимо, сделать так, чтобы при наведении на текст, изображение, которое перед текстом вращалось.
Картинка - **текст**. Наводим на текст курсор и картинка делает полный оборот вокруг оси.

```css
.img {
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -ms-border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .8s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .8s;
  -o-transition: all ease .8s;
  transition: all ease .8s;
}
.text:hover ~ .img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

На данный момент работает только если картинка идет после текста. Если поставить **текст** - картинка - то все работает.
Вот html код:

```html
<img class="img" src="/images/copy.jpg" alt="Не работает" />
<p class="text">123</p>
<img class="img" src="/images/copy.jpg" alt="Работает" />
```

В идеале было бы сделать так:

```html
<a class="text" href="">
  <img class="img" src="/images/copy.jpg" alt="Имя" />Сообщение</a>
```

То есть сделать так, чтобы при наведении на ссылку, прокручивалось изображение которое в ней находится. При этом сам текст стоит на месте.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS, в отличие от JQuery, не умеет "идти вверх по коду", только вниз. Поэтому, и `+`, и `~` выберут только следующий элемент (плюсик - подряд, тильда - не подряд).

Источник и возможные костыли: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector

Нормальное решение - обернуть и картинку, и текст в один элемент, например, `<a>`:

```css
.img {
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -ms-border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .8s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .8s;
  -o-transition: all ease .8s;
  transition: all ease .8s;
}
.text:hover > .img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<a class="text" href="">
  <img class="img" src="/images/copy.jpg" alt="Имя" />Сообщение</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qkfLr1oa/

Comment: хорошо, можно ли сделать так, чтобы вращалась картинка находящаяся в ссылке?
<a class="text" href="">
  <img class="img" src="/images/copy.jpg" alt="Имя" />Сообщение</a>

Comment: Готово, добавил в ответ.

Comment: Ответ-то правильный, но я не понял где ошибся. Моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я не использовал > ? Так что-ли?

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что оба элемента были siblings, т.е. находлись на одном уровне: `<img><p>текст</p>`, поэтому мы не могли вращать нужный нам `<img>`, зная `<p>`.

Тогда мы поменяли код на такой: `<a><img>текст</a>`, т.е. картинка стала `child`, т.е. вложенным элементом. Зная нужный нам `<a>` мы легко можем анимировать его дочерний элемент `<img>`.

Еще раз: выбрать *предыдущий элемент на том же уровне* через CSS нельзя. Можно выбрать *вложенный элемент* или *следующий на том же уровне*.